# Hibernate ResultTransformer with JPA API

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Has anyone figured out a smart way to do query result transformation through a similar mechanism like specifying a [ResultTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html) in Hibernate?

All I can think of is transforming each result row after it has been returned by the Query. Is there any other way?

For constructor projections (e.g. new DTO(arg1, arg2)) it can be defined in the JPQL query, but how about other cases?

My use case is the following :

I am working on a [custom Tuple projection](http://source.mysema.com/forum/mvnforum/viewthread_thread,68) for [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/), but I can't yet get it working properly with JPA. It is difficult with constructor projection, since I also need to supply the query expressions, not only the result values.

In general other use cases could also be JavaBean population (public empty construction invocation and setter-based population), using a factory method for object creation etc.

Comment: Do you mean for native queries? Also, why *"at least for Hibernate"*? A constructor expression in the select clause is standard JPQL.

Comment: I corrected the constructor expression part, and no, I don't mean native queries, but JPQL queries.

Comment: It's certainly me but I don't get what the other cases are. Do you have an example in mind?

Comment: I'll think again about this but this goes obviously beyond standard JPA.

Comment: Yes, I guess what I am searching for might be a hack. Although I believe the need is not too uncommon.

Comment: Until now, the constructor expression has covered my needs. But others might have a different point of view (BTW, you should use the twitter-like @username syntax when replying to comments if you want people to get [notified](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with [EclipseLink JPA implementation](http://onpersistence.blogspot.com/2010/07/eclipselink-jpa-native-constructor.html).

Comment: Thanks, this will give me EclipseLink support for custom projections.